# Outgoing links not opening because of smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

For my anchorlinks I have set smooth scrolling, that is working. Also every outgoing link is working but not the outgoing links in the navigation (see green arrow in picture). Its producing a uncaught reference error. Why is this and how to solve this?

question is regarding this site: https://bm-translations.de/km.php

I had this problem at the beginning for all links and I could solve it with this code:

```js
// Captures click events of all <a> elements with href starting with #
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {

  // Click events are captured before hashchanges. Timeout
  // causes offsetAnchor to be called after the page jump.

  window.setTimeout(function () {
    // offsetAnchor();
  }, 0);
});

// Set the offset when entering page with hash present in the url
window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you might be using offset() incorrectly - http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: @Adam I am not sure what you mean? Or is there maybe a way like in CSS :not() to do not target a certain class with this smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is the css `:not()` selector for excluding specific class from this function:

```
//Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link

$(document).on("click", ".navbar-nav a:not('.externallink')", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();



  $("html, body").animate(

    {

      scrollTop: $($.prop(this, "hash")).offset().top

    },

    500

  );

});
```